# JS - Get new element after click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, wait

I'm working on a chrome extension to automate some work of mine. Currently it enters a value into a input, then clicks the button.

I want to get a new div element when it gets to the next page (once loaded). But it always looking a div before click event.
I hope that you understanded my problem.

Here is a code:

```
bSzukaj.onclick = function()
        {
            var url = "/game.php?screen=place";
            var coords = [];
            var loaded = false;
            var n = inputZakres.value;
            var x = parseInt(inputPobierz.value.split("|")[0] - parseInt(n/2+1));
            var y = parseInt(inputPobierz.value.split("|")[1] - parseInt(n/2+1));


            var newWindow = window.open(url);
            var currentX = x;
            var currentY = y;
            var coord = currentX+"|"+currentY;

            var sender = newWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){

                var spearInput = newWindow.document.getElementById("unit_input_spear");
                spearInput.value = 10;

                var coordClass = newWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("target-input-field target-input-autocomplete")[0];
                coordClass.value = coord;

                var send = newWindow.document.getElementById("target_attack").click();
               // NOW SCRIPT RELOAD PAGE AND CREATING SOME COMUNICATS
               // AND I WANT TO GET THIS COMUNICATS TO VARIABLE
               // BUT EVEN THIS ALERT BELOW DOESN'T WORK :/
                newWindow.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    alert("now");
                });

            }, false);

            //}
            //}
        }
    }
```

Comment: you lose the state after the refresh of the page

Comment: What can i do with that?

Comment: do with what???

Comment: How can i continue script after click event?

Comment: save and get the state after refresh

Comment: Can you explain how ?

Comment: use localstorage/cookies